# Unable to import modules in VS Code despite setting PYTHONPATH in launch.json and settings.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module

I'm working on a Python project in Visual Studio Code, and I'm having trouble importing custom modules located in separate directories. I've already set up the `PYTHONPATH` in both launch.json and settings.json, but I still get a ModuleNotFoundError.

Here's my project structure:

```
.
├── .vscode
│   ├── launch.json
│   └── settings.json
├── house_mgt
│   └── main.py
└── repos
    ├── configs
    │   └── ...
    └── functions
        └── house_functions.py
```

I have the following launch.json configuration:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "house_mgt.main",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/repos/configs/:${workspaceFolder}/repos/functions/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my settings.json file:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/repos/configs/",
        "${workspaceFolder}/repos/functions/"
    ]
}
```

In my main.py file, I'm trying to import the house_functions module like this:

```
from house_functions import create_data_preprocessor
```

However, when I run main.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/me/Documents/Raven/code/house_mgt/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from house_functions import create_data_preprocessor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'house_functions'
```

I would like to keep my project structure as is and not modify my Python files directly to include paths. How can I correctly configure my VS Code project to find and import the house_functions module without encountering the ModuleNotFoundError? I am running on mac m1 machine and the code imports functions fine if i open the project in pycharm. I would also prefer not to have to run the file from command line.

Comment: what is the value of `PYTHONPATH` in the script

Comment: the `settings.json` config has nothing to do with running Python scripts, the hint is `analysis`

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH does not return anything if typed into the terminal in VS Code but returns the desired paths in terminal on mac.

Comment: NO, determine the value of `PYTHONPATH` **IN** your Python script

Comment: You need to know if your environment setting from launch config makes it to the script

Comment: print("PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH", "Not set")) gives Not set.

Comment: first get that solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.env` file.

Add the `.env` file under workspace folder.

**.env**

```
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/functions
```

Then add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

When you use **debug** mode, it can find this folder.